# Subscription to webcal event in iOS Safari not working but works on OSX

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, icalendar

I have exported an event in the .ics format from iCal and linked to the file from an event site i am creating.

When i navigate the link in Chrome on my MacBook it correctly opens iCal and subscribes to the event.

However when i navigate to the same page in iPhone Safari and navigate the link it retrieves an error where it says it cannot subscribe to the calendar.

Am unsure as to why it is working in one and not the other:

http://tfma2012.valtechdigital.co.uk/

The calendar location is as follows:

```
webcal://tfma2012.valtechdigital.co.uk/calendar/TFMA.ics
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using "webcal://" as the address, simply use "http://"; it worked perfectly for me on both my Mac and iPhone when I tried that.

Comment: @RyanP13 I had to use https in my case.  File -> New Calendar Subscription -> replace webcal with https and it was added as a new calendar

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code and check

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openUrl:[NSUrl urlWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"webcal://tfma2012.valtechdigital.co.uk/calendar/TFMA.ics"];

Answer (score 0):

- If you use `http://` so usage of `Content-Type: text/calendar` HTTP header considered (Not tested) personally You can use same page name with `text/html` header for desktop browsers to show "how to" manual.
- If you use `webcal://` it is also well supported on iOS, the header must be `Content-Type: text/calendar` (Tested, works on iOS 13)

You can go even further and show url like `webcal://example.com/schedule/?staff_id=1245` encoded in QR code. On camera mode iOS device will suggest you to subscribe to the iCalendar feed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the link is just outdated.  Open your calendar, turn off the public link and turn it on, the new address will work